# How to make FB preview that is just image? (like damnlol.com)

Tags: image, facebook, preview

I have one problem which doesn't let me sleep at night. How to make Facebook preview like www.damnlol.com? That the preview is just an image, nothing else, no title, no description.

I'm trying to figure this out for a week now and still no success. Fb debbuger was of no help, so wasn't google or YouTube. I actually got that sad that I send an email to damnlol.com asking for the solution.

So please, pretty please, if anybody knows how to do it let me/us know. As I found one similar topic elsewhere but it wasn't solved.

Comment: There is no way to force this. Facebook decides when to display title and description, or not.

Comment: This question is not really on topic for SO.